# Javascript understanding

Tags: javascript

This is probably a stupidly basic question for this community, but if someone could explain it to me I would be very great full, I am so confused by it.  I found this tutorial on the net and this was example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sports (x){
        alert("I love " + x);
    }
    sports ("Football");
    sports ("Rally");
    sports ("Rugby");
</script>
```

Why does this display the 3 variables: Football, Rally and Rugby?

Is it because x = sports? So when the variables of sports are defined they get displayed?

I think I confused myself more when writing this so I hope it kind of makes sense :(

Comment: Do you know what a function is?

Comment: You may want make friends with js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/  - experiment, save and share when you get stuck, makes life a lot easier when you get to more complicated stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the reason it shows all three variables (sequentially, not simultaneously) is because you're calling the function three times, each time you call it you're passing a variable (`"Football"` for example), which the function uses internally to complete the alerted message.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a function, called "sports", that takes one argument, named "x". Each time you call the function, it alerts a message, substituting the argument you pass in for "x". In this example, you call the function three times, with three different values of "x".

Comment: I only started learning JavaScript about an hour ago so I had to look up some of the phrases you used but I get it now, thanks very much :)

Comment: ... how I wish there was StackOverflow when I was an hour into learning javascript ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you, x is a container for a value. So when you say something like `sports ("Football");` it behaves as if this:

```
alert("I love " + x);
```

was actually this:

```
alert("I love " + "Football");
```

This is because `x` contains `"Football"`.

Think of it as a placeholder for a value of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write sports("text") you call a function. It means that it is executed.

Your function is displaying an alert message using an argument. In your case you execute your function three times with 3 different arguments.